# error after installation of netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: java, netbeans-7

hello Please Just to start with am new to java ME....i just download the netbeans iDE 7.3.1 yesterday after i finish installation i try to run there sample java application but all  got is this error message..

```
ERROR - Ant is misconfigured and cannot be run.
java.io.IOException: Could not load class org.netbeans.modules.javame.profiler.ant.OpenProfiler: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/netbeans/modules/javame/profiler/ant/OpenProfiler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.loadDefs(AntBridge.java:561)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.createCustomDefs(AntBridge.java:538)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.createAntInstance(AntBridge.java:326)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.getAntInstance(AntBridge.java:279)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.getInterface(AntBridge.java:268)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/netbeans/modules/javame/profiler/ant/OpenProfiler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AuxClassLoader.findClass(AuxClassLoader.java:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.loadDefs(AntBridge.java:550)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: loading: org.netbeans.modules.javame.profiler.ant.OpenProfiler
```

please help i just dont know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-150397.html), "The classes are compiled for a newer JVM than you try to run with. Use a newer JDK."

Comment: You So Correct i uninstall the jdk1.6 i was using and install the latest one which is 1.7... its now working the java ME Sdk 3.3 is coming on when ever  i run or try to debug my program thanks so much